# Template backend entry form

Tags: templating, entry

Can the backend entry form be adjusted by a template. It's not a very compressed view.
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1ps0.png)
[image]

It would look a lot better if I can add some float:left; to parts.
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnErL.png)
[image]

Comment: A follow up question. Is it possible to moving some of those fields into the right panel where the enabled switch is too? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CP CSS to accomplish that...

> https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss

Comment: Ah that looks good. Thanks.

**One follow up question though.** How about moving some of those fields into the right panel where the enabled switch is too? Is that possible?

Comment: You could use [CP JS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs) to dynamically move the fields.